# why i am receiving the null value ??How to resolve this?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

i am sending post request in api controller using postman i tried two ways for it first i use viewmodel i got null values and after that i used jObject as a recieved parameter of post it get the value but when i try to convert the value  it into object it failed to it and through exception..here is my code..

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCommunityAsync(JObject json_obj)
 {
        dynamic jsondata = json_obj;//In this get recieve value there

        JObject com = jsondata.Community;//gets null com contains null after 
        the breakpoint hit...Community is my MOdel class//

        var commu = com.ToObject<Community>();
        var community = commu.ToObject<Community>();//through null referene 
         exception//
        await _as.abc(commu);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Show the viewmodel and the data being sent

Comment: public class CreateCommunityViewModel
         {
                 public Community com { get; set; }
                public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
        }

Comment: Why do have the line that declares jsondata ? Your object named json_obj should already have been deserialized/instantiated so there is no need for jsondata. If json_obj is null then the data you received could not be deserialized correctly.

Comment: You should be looking for the cause of your problem in the code that is making the call and not in the handler method.